# Magento CMS Page vs Static Blocks

Tags: category, cms, cms-block

I am setting up a Magento store and it has a lot of CMS content.

I have been fiddling between:

1. Creating categories and actual CMS page with corresponding URL then rewrite the categories url to the CMS Page
2. Creating categories and and static blocks (with CMS content) and just link the categories to the right static block.

It seems to me the latter solution is less of a hassle and cleaner, but is there any con in doing this ?

Comment: Both ways should be fine, you should be thinking more in terms of SEO perspective, which case would give you better management of Page title, keywords etc.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly if you want to create small blocks on given page then you should go for static block with category. In this case you have easy option to add products also as it is category page you can select product as well as static block.

If you are creating page like about us or contact us page where you have full pages content only then you should go for CMS page as it is easy to change the contents on a single place.

Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

**A page** this includes any extra page on your store (other than the category page and the product page) such as About us page, Terms and conditions etc.

**A Static block** on the other hand includes any content on your page, this is found on the home page, category page or product page. An example of static blocks, is footer links, banner images and side banners.

**Managing Pages** This can be managed by going to CMS > Pages Once on that page, you will notice a number of existing pages on your store where you can either click on or edit or you can simply add a new page.

**Managing static blocks**
Static blocks allows you to add different content types on your store pages. These include images, maps, footer links, homepage products, contact info, newsletter subscription etc.

for more detail follow [this](http://support.shopgo.me/hc/en-us/articles/202115902-Pages-vs-Static-blocks)