# Using a Page vs. a Static Block

Tags: static-block, cms-block, cms-pages, page

I'm trying to get a very basic understanding of when I should use a `Page` vs. `Static Block` to create content for the site. Can someone provide examples of where they might be used? Or scenarios where you use the two together?

Answer (score 1):

Some basic info you can find on this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82243/magento-cms-page-vs-static-blocks) where someone already asked kind of same question. if you still need more insights magento documentation is best place to read.